# Sony Xperia U with my Windows XP laptop

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, usb-drivers

I have Windows XP and every time I connect my Xperia U, the computer thinks it a camera. I think it's a driver problem so I found the drivers on the Sony Website, but I'm not sure how to install them?

I installed the drivers, but my computer still thinks it's a camera. Any help?

Comment: It there any USB connectivity setting? Normally phones have settings like connect to PC as: Camera, Storage, Android phone, etc. Can you just verify these settings?

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with the MTP driver in Windows XP. It will connect in PTP mode thats why it is showing as camera. You can search in Microsoft forum for enabling MTP but still not sure whether it will work or not. Change the os or install Sony PC companion

Answer (score 0):

If you've upgraded from gingerbread, Android 4.0 does not allow for direct mounting of the phone memory/sd. This means that your phone will show up as either a media player or camera.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the phone set to connect in PTP mode.  When you connect, there should be a notification that you've connected to a computer.

Open that notification and it should allow you to select a different mode, usually either MSC (mass storage, used on pre-4.0) or MTP (media transfer, 4.0 and newer).

Alternatively, look in the settings for a USB connection mode option.